# how to run php script that export to excel file daily in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script that export result to an excel file. However, I need to run thatscript daily at specific time of a day and export excel file save it in the server daily. I use nginx, php7 and ubuntu 16.04 as my web server. Please advise how to do this.

Thank you in advance.
Hiroshi

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Go to `/etc/cron.d`
- Create a file: `export`
- Edit file with following code (change the time when you want to execute your script)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## Scripts
#00 01 * * * root nice php /path/to/your/php/script
```